# Whenever I try to compile javascript code I get a syntax error

Tags: javascript, compilation

Whenever I try to run my code I keep getting a syntax error the specifics of the error are here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H73LR.png

I don't think it has to do anything with the file format because it is in a .js file I also ran a

antivirus to see if that was causing it( a site online said viruses could cause this error) my code is as follows:

````
const firstName = 'William'; 
const lastname = 'Johnson';

let val;

val = firstName + lastname;

console.log(val)```
````

Comment: Why will you compile a JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image seems you're trying to look up the `.js` file directly from your browser.

You can't look up a `.js` file directly from your browser, the browser can't parse it.

You should create an **HTML** file i.e a `.html` file and link your script to it.

E.g
In your HTML file

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="your script source.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, so I think it's your antivirus causing this problem. Try disabling your antivirus and run your code again.

Comment: Yea I uninstalled it after it got the results which was zero viruses do you think it could have anything to do with the extensions on VSC? or any of the other files in the folder